# Subspaces of $L_p([0,1])$ whose unit ball is compact for the topology of convergence in measure

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, compactness

Any information about the following questions would be welcome.

1. I wonder whether there are (well-known or easy) closed and infinite dimensional subspaces of $L_p([0,1])$ ($1<p<\infty$) whose unit ball is compact for the topology of convergence in measure.
2. If they do exist, can they be described or characterized? (Do they linearly embed into $\ell_p$ or into $\ell_2$?)

Note that, in the case $p=1$, such subspaces of $L_1([0,1])$ were already considered in the literature. For instance, in a paper called "On subspaces of $L^1$ which embed into $\ell_1$", G. Godefroy, N.J. Kalton and D.Li obtained a description of the subspaces whose unit ball is compact and locally convex in measure (Thereom 3.3 and Corollary 3.5 therein). In their words: "*Corollary 3.5 somehow means that the subspaces of $L^1$ whose unit ball is i $\tau_m$-compact locally convex are close to the trivial ones, that is, to w$^*$-closed subspaces of copies of $\ell_1$ generated in $L^1$ by a sequence of disjoint indicator functions.*" 
However, there exist subspaces of $L^1$ whose unit ball is compact but not locally convex in measure (Theorem 4.1 therein).

Comment: Theorem 4.4 in  the [paper](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0823.46018) N. Kalton, DW, ``Property (M), M-ideals, and almost isometric structure of Banach spaces.'' J. Reine Angew. Math. 461, 137-178 (1995) says about a subspace $X\subset L_p[0,1]$, $1<p<\infty$, $p\neq2$,  that $X$ embeds almost isometrically into $\ell_p$ if and only if $B_X$ is $L_1$-compact. (This paper is the predecessor of the one you are quoting.) For those spaces, the unit ball is compact in measure.  Concerning embeddings into $\ell_p$ see also W.B. Johnson and E. Odell's [paper](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0282.46020).

Comment: @DirkWerner This is exactly the kind of result I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help (and for the precise references).

Answer (score -1):

No, it does not: otherwise, the given closed subspace $V$ would be a subspace of $L^0$ (the space of measurable functions, metrised with the convergence in measure) whose unit ball would be compact, and thus $V$ would be a topological vector space in which every ball is compact.
This implies that $V$ is finite dimensional, since

*Every locally compact topological vector space $X$ has finite dimension*: see Theorem 1.22 in

> Rudin, Walter. "Functional analysis." (1973).

Comment: That is not a valid argument. Locally compact means that some neighbourhood of $0$ is compact. But the unit ball of the $L^p$-norm on $V$ need not be a $L^0$-neighbourhood. (Your argument would implay that every compact operator between Banach spaces had finite dimensional range.)

Comment: ah ah! You are totally right, I got confused between the intersection of $V$ with the unit ball in $L^p$, and the unit ball in $L^0$, which are of course very different things